# Sy-fy movie where a monster appears on a kid's bed

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, sy-fy

Years ago I saw this movie on SyFy I think. I don't know the name but I remember this scene where this kid's mom goes to check the closet for monsters. She says "See? No monsters" then she turns around and this large alien monster thing is on top of the kid's bed.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nquLT-r4eyU - Little Monsters?

Comment: Is the mother surprised by the presence of the monster on the bed?

Comment: Hogfather? The Governess, not the mother

Comment: It's a Bogeyman!

Comment: Valorum yeah she was terrified. She was screaming when the camera panned to the bed.